# unshare -m not creating mount namespace

Tags: linux

I ran

```
unshare -mfp sh -c 'mount -tproc none /proc ; ls /proc'
```

As expected, that printed a /proc with only directories for PID 1 and PID 3, and exited, leaving me back in my old prompt in the root namespace.

Then I did

```
ls /proc
```

and I got back a listing without any PID directories. I was expecting my usual /proc full of processes. I had to mount proc again to fix things.

Why is this happening? How do I fix things so the /proc I mounted inside the PID namespace stays local to it?

I tried passing --mount-private to mount, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

I'm on Amazon Linux 2016.03 which comes with util-linux 2.23.2.

Comment: I was intrigued by your problem and I have spent some time investigating the same effect on Ubuntu. I found that the command gave `write failed /proc/self/gid_map: Operation not permitted` unless I gave `root` privileges; when I did this it behaved as you describe, and all users lost PID and mount access: only rebooting allowed me to recover. My reading of the manual concurs with yours, so I conclude that either we are both misunderstanding, or the implementation is completely wrong. In either case, I can't see a way to a solution, other than to try some of the coding examples.

Comment: I found [this article](https://www.toptal.com/linux/separation-anxiety-isolating-your-system-with-linux-namespaces) and [this series](https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/#series_index) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either unshare(1) is broken or I am stupid.

I modified the code in http://crosbymichael.com/creating-containers-part-1.html so it would actually work for me. Had to umount /proc lazily with `umount2`, and include `linux/sched.h` instead of `sched.h`.

To compile do `gcc foo.c -ofoo`.

You will note that after running, e.g `./foo ls /proc`, /proc on the host system won't be wiped out.

```
//
// This compiles and works on Amazon Linux 2016.03 (kernel 4.4.5-15.26.amzn1.x86_64)
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// was <sched.h>, but wouldn't compile on Amazon Linux
#include <linux/sched.h>
// for umount2()
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define STACKSIZE (1024*1024)
static char child_stack[STACKSIZE];

struct clone_args {
        char **argv;
};

static int child_exec(void *stuff) {
        struct clone_args *args = (struct clone_args *)stuff;

        // the fprintf()s crash. Not sure why.

        // changed from umount(), lazy umount succeeds
        if (umount2("/proc", MNT_DETACH) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to unmount /proc: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(-1);
        }

        if (mount("proc", "/proc", "proc", 0, "") != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to mount /proc: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(-1);
        }

        if (execvp(args->argv[0], args->argv) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to execvp arguments: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(-1);
        }

        // unreachable
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        struct clone_args args;
        args.argv = &argv[1];

        int clone_flags = CLONE_NEWPID | CLONE_NEWNS | SIGCHLD;
        pid_t pid = clone(child_exec, child_stack + STACKSIZE, clone_flags, &args);

        if (pid < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "clone failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to wait pid %d\n", pid);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mount propagation is enabled, probably by systemd, and you a using what is now an old version of `unshare` that does change the propagation state, as a result all mount operations in the new mount namespace are reflected in the original namespace.